# Page become white

Tags: php

Hello I have a error on my page.. When i go to www.mysite.com/request.php the page is just white..

```
    <?php
include("../includes/config.php");
include("../includes/functions.php");
######
include('../config_radio.php'); //you may edit this path to fit your server environment otherwise leave it alone
$scfp = fsockopen("$scip", $scport, &$errno, &$errstr, 30);
if(!$scfp) {
$scsuccs=1;
echo''.$scdef.' is Offline';
}
if($scsuccs!=1){
fputs($scfp,"GET /admin.cgi?pass=$scpass&mode=viewxml HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: SHOUTcast Song Status (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n");
while(!feof($scfp)) {
$page .= fgets($scfp, 1000);
}

###########################################################
///////////////////////// Part 1 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
###########################################################

//define xml elements
$loop = array("STREAMSTATUS", "BITRATE", "SERVERTITLE", "CURRENTLISTENERS");
$y=0;
while($loop[$y]!=''){
$pageed = ereg_replace(".*<$loop[$y]>", "", $page);
$scphp = strtolower($loop[$y]);
$$scphp = ereg_replace("</$loop[$y]>.*", "", $pageed);
if($loop[$y]==SERVERGENRE || $loop[$y]==SERVERTITLE || $loop[$y]==SONGTITLE || $loop[$y]==SERVERTITLE)
$$scphp = urldecode($$scphp);

// uncomment the next line to see all variables
//echo'$'.$scphp.' = '.$$scphp.'<br>';
$y++;
}
//end intro xml elements

###########################################################
///////////////////////// Part 2 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
###########################################################

//get song info and history
$pageed = ereg_replace(".*<SONGHISTORY>", "", $page);
$pageed = ereg_replace("<SONGHISTORY>.*", "", $pageed);
$songatime = explode("<SONG>", $pageed);
$r=1;
while($songatime[$r]!=""){
$t=$r-1;
$playedat[$t] = ereg_replace(".*<PLAYEDAT>", "", $songatime[$r]);
$playedat[$t] = ereg_replace("</PLAYEDAT>.*", "", $playedat[$t]);
$song[$t] = ereg_replace(".*<TITLE>", "", $songatime[$r]);
$song[$t] = ereg_replace("</TITLE>.*", "", $song[$t]);
$song[$t] = urldecode($song[$t]);
$dj[$t] = ereg_replace(".*<SERVERTITLE>", "", $page);
$dj[$t] = ereg_replace("</SERVERTITLE>.*", "", $pageed);
$r++;
}
//end song info

fclose($scfp);
}
########
if($_GET['sendreq'] == "true" && $_GET['dj']  && $_GET['name'] && $_GET['type'] && $_GET['message']) {

$name = $_GET['name'];
$dj = $_GET['dj'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$message = $_GET['message'];

$name = clean($name);
$dj = clean($dj);
$type = clean($type);
$message = clean($message);
$name = censor($name);
$dj = censor($dj);
$type = censor($type);
$message = censor($message);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$a1 = date("r");

$a2 = explode(" ", $a1);

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO requests (`name`, `dj`, `type`, `msg`, `time`, `ip`) VALUES ('$name', '$dj', '$type', '$message', '$a2[4]', '$ip')") or die('Could not send request! Error: '.mysql_error());

echo('<strong>Thanks!</strong> Your message has been sent to the DJ specified!');

die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Request Line</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#title { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
#sub_title { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; }
#text { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: none; }
#results { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: none; }
input { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: none; }
select { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: none; }
textarea { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: none; }
-->
</style>
<script>
var xmlHttp 

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{ 
    var objXMLHttp = null 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { 
        objXMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest() 
        }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        { 
        objXMLHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    } 
    return objXMLHttp 
} 

function sendreq() {
// Open function
// Set object
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject() 
    if (xmlHttp == null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
        return
    }
// We have set teh object


// Check for empty strings

if(document.request.type.value == "") {
            alert("You must select a type of request!")
            return
}

if(document.request.name.value == "") {
            alert("You must enter a name!")
            return
}

if(document.request.message.value == "") {
            alert("You must enter a message!")
            return
}

// We have alerted if any strings are emptyyy

var url = "request.php?sendreq=true&dj="+document.request.dj.value+"&name="+document.request.name.value+"&type="+document.request.type.value+"&message="+document.request.message.value

xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = "" // This removes the form, stopping them from sending the same request over and over again - SMART, EH?

}
};
xmlHttp.send(null);

// Now we clear out the forms and hide the form to TRY to prevent spamz!

// End function
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span id="title">Kontakta studion</span><br />
<span id="sub_title">Edit the css for this to fit YOUR site!</span>
<br />
<br />
<div id="form" name="form" style="display: block">
<form method="post" name="request" onsubmit="sendreq();return false;">
<span id="text"><strong>

Radio DJ:<br />
<label>
<select name="dj" id="dj">
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE level != 'banned'") or die('ERROR '.mysql_error());
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
if(preg_match("/". $rows[username] ."/i", $servertitle)) {
echo("<option value='". $rows[username] ."' SELECTED>DJ ". $rows[username] ." lol</option>");
} else {
echo("<option value='". $rows[username] ."'>DJ ". $rows[username] ."</option>");
}
}
?>
</select></label>
</strong><br />
<br />
<strong>Ditt Namn:</strong><br />
<label>
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" />
</label> 
<br />
<br />
<strong>Typ:</strong><br />


<label>
<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="request">Låtönskning</option>
  <option value="shoutout">Hälsning</option>
  <option value="competition">Tävlingssvar</option>
  <option value="joke">Skämt</option>
</select>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<strong>Meddelande:</strong></span>
<br />
<label>
<textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="4" id="message"></textarea>
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Skicka!" />
</label>
</form>
<br /><br />
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thats the code... I got 500 Internal Server Error

Any help on whats wrong with this?

I have search on google but no answer there... Maybe I search wrong but anyway. I hope to get some help here instead :).

Comment: turn on error reporting

Comment: There may be any errors in your code.. Once remove error_reporting() and check if there are any errors..

Comment: Depending on the version of PHP you're running: `$scfp = fsockopen("$scip", $scport, &$errno, &$errstr, 30);`.... `Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed`

Comment: ereg_replace : Warning

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on error reporting by editing your php.ini file.

Inside your php.ini file, you will find two settings - `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. You should set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`, and `display_errors` to `1`. Restart your webserver, and reload your page. You should now see a more descriptive error message.

Note that other answers ask you to enable error reporting at **runtime**, but not all errors are triggered at runtime. Parse errors (eg bad syntax) will be triggered before your code is even run, and so the error config will still be using the values defined in the php.ini file, still leaving you with a blank page.

As a side note, PHP errors may also be reported to the web server's event log (the location of which will vary on web server and operating system), even if error_reporting is disabled.

Comment: This should only be done for development - for production it is best to use logging.

Comment: The same is true of adding ini_set('display_errors',1). My answer was written assuming that the asker is working in a development environment, not a production one :)

Answer (score 0):

Before `while` loop on line 13 you need to set `$page` variable, so:

```
$page = "";
while(!feof($scfp)) {
    $page .= fgets($scfp, 1000);
}
```

In while loop you add st. to undefined `$page`, so you need to define that first.

Comment: Although this will cause a warning, it will not stop the page from being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on error reporting.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

You will get the error by this.

Comment: Before include("../includes/config.php");

Comment: @Pupil That won't always show errors. If there's a parse error, it won't even get to that statement and enable error reporting. The correct place to enable it is php.ini.